# Trying to fork a process, first command works but second always gives an error

Tags: c++, shell, unix, process, fork

So currently I'm creating a shell interface that accepts user commands and then executes each command in a separate process. It took me a bit to get the input correctly into the character array. (Had to parse it and divide each input i.e. args[0] = ls, args[1] = -l). I'm pretty sure I did that part right but think that's what is giving me an issue.

So after I parse the input, I create a child process to execute the arguments using execvp system call. In my parent process, I have a conditional statement that calls the Wait() function if the last part of the command had an ampersand in it.

So the issue I'm facing is that when I execute this code, I'm able to properly execute the first command, but no matter what the second command is, I get an error. I'm thinking that it has something to do with not clearing the array afterwards but having a hard time narrowing this issue down. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 //the maximum length command

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char* args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; //command line arguments
  char str[41]; //intitialize string for input
  int should_run = 1; //flag to determine when to exit program
  int index = 0;
  pid_t pid; //process id

  while (should_run) {
    cout << "prompt> ";
    fflush(stdout);

    cin.getline(str, 41);

    args[index] = strtok(str, " ");

    while (args[index] != NULL) {
      // test      cout << args[index] << endl;
      index++;
      args[index] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    args[index + 1] = NULL;

    if (strcmp (args[0], "exit") == 0) //in input is "exit", exit the while loop
      break;

    // (1) fork a child process using fork()
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { //error handling
      perror("Fork Failed.");
      break;
    }
    // (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
    if (pid == 0) {
      //child process
      cout << "child:" << pid << endl;
      execvp (args[0], args);
    }

    // (3) if command didn't included &, parent will invoke wait()
    //parent process
    if (pid > 0)
      {
        // parent process
        if (strcmp (args[index], "&") == 0) {
          wait(0);
          cout << "parent: " << pid << endl;
        }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bug is very obvious. And I'm sure that once you use your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables, you will be able to figure out your bug by yourself. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Free clue: use your debugger to show the value of `index`, on the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik any chance you could recommend one? I've yet to learn how to use one properly. Now would be a good time to start.

Comment: On Linux and Unix, `gdb` rules the roost. There's only one debugger, of note.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my index should've been initialized within the while loop huh?

Comment: Pretty much so.

Comment: The debugger is a very powerful tool. You can get simple diagnostics without it, by putting output statements here and there in your code, such as `cout << "third point, index is " << index << endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to reinitialise `index` to 0 when you are parsing the second and subsequent commands.